# TDE - looking for help setting up encryption keys and certificates across multiple SQL servers

Tags: sql-server, transparent-data-encryption

I'm looking for some direction on best practices for maintaining encryption keys and certificates across multiple MS SQL servers.

I'm planning to create a separate master key with a separate password for each SQL server (prod/dev/test) and back up to a separate file.

For certificates, I plan to set up separate certificates by application groupings.  For example, the certificate that is used to encrypt the production database for App A would be shared with the Dev/Test servers for App A.

Is this a reasonable, thorough approach?

Thanks!

Comment: These sound like questions you should be asking your infosec people. In some places sharing encryption keys between production and development would trigger a resume refresh event.

Comment: is there a vulnerability with sharing the master key?  

If I'm to restore a prod db onto a dev/test server, I think I need to have the same cert in place?

Comment: Let me attempt to clarify:
Should I
a) create separate master keys on all servers with different passwords and store each of them securely?
b) create a master key, back it up and use the backup to restore on each of the other servers?  Thus, I only have one key to store.

Production databases will need to be restored onto Dev/Test servers.  I assume I will need to create a cert on the prod server and then load that same cert on the Dev/Test server?

Comment: Please [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/323369/edit) your question if you feel it needs clarification, but my suggestion still stands -- this is the question that needs to be first answered by the people responsible for data security and compliance in your organisation.

Comment: The infosec people are not familiar with the intricacies of SQL keys/certs.  What should I tell them would be the vulnerabilities with a shared master key?

Comment: I guess in the same category as a shared root password?

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio.  So I think I'm landing on this solution:
-every server has its own master key, backed up with a separate password
-servers with prod dbs have a cert (AppXcert), backed up with its own pw
-prod/dev servers that will have copies of prod dbs will need to have that cert loaded on it (AppXcert)

did I get that right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very familiar with how TDE works; perhaps you can update your question to reflect your final approach and other people can chime in.

Comment: Why do you need a password to protect the DMK, you can protect it using the master database, ie using a Service Master Key. The SMK itself does not need backing up.